# Selecting Specific Pages in a Userform when MultiPages are Nested

Tags: excel, vba, userform, multipage

I have a single userform with 3 "top-level" pages (using the multipage functionality) and then four nested pages each within two of the top-level pages.

#### Screenshot of Nested Multipage Userform

[image: Screenshot of Nested Multipage Userform]

In this example, the page captions and names are the same. Therefore, the page with the caption of Page4 is also named Page4. I found code online that is supposed to return the page index when the page name is passed to it:

```
Function fMpIndex(ByVal PageName As String)

    Dim PageCounter As Long

    With MultiPage1

        For PageCounter = 0 To .Pages.Count - 1

            If .Pages(PageCounter).Name = PageName Then fMpIndex = PageCounter: Exit Function
        Next PageCounter
    End With
    fMpIndex = -1

End Function
```

This works for the top-level pages, however, when I try something like:

```
MsgBox ("This page's index is " & fMpIndex("Page5"))
```

for any of the nested pages (in this example, both pages 4 & 5), then this method returns a value of -1, indicating that the page does not exist. Is this a scope issue? Does the code above only search for the top-level pages and not the nested pages?

What is the safest, most reliable way to programmatically reference a specific page by either name or caption or both? I assume it would be something like:

```
which userform.which page strip.which page.name("Page5")
```

In this example, I only have one userform, but what if I had two userforms? Also, in the above example, I am assuming that one must specify which of the two page strips are being referenced.

Ideally, I want a way to use an absolute reference to each page in the userform regardless of whether it is a top-level page or a nested page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot, the only pages in MultiPage1 are Page1, Page2, and Page3. These can be referenced using (for example) `MultiPage1.Pages("Page1")`. `MultiPage1.Pages("Page4")` does not exist.

Page1 contains MultiPage2, and its pages are Page4 and Page5. These can be references using `MultiPage2.Pages("Page4")`.

You can reference pages in a MultiPage control by index, as in `MultiPage1.Pages(iPageIndex)`, where iPageIndex goes from 0 to the number of pages minus one. In your screenshot, `MultiPage1.Pages(1)` references Page2, and 
`MultiPage2.Pages(0)` references Page4.